# getting error in posting video on facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am making an app in which i want to post video on facebook.I am getting this error:

```
08-27 16:51:49.001: W/Facebook-Example(16413): Facebook Error: (#351) Video file was corrupt or invalidnullOAuthException(#351) Video file was corrupt or invalid
```

This is the code:

```
mUploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                byte[] data = null;
                AssetFileDescriptor fileDesc = getResources().openRawResourceFd(
                R.raw.test);
                //String dataPath = //"http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp";//"android.resource://com.facebook.android/raw/mo//vie"; //fileDesc.toString();
                String dataMsg = "Your video description here.";
                String dataName = "test.3gp";

                Bundle param;
                AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
                InputStream is ;
                try 
                {
                    is = fileDesc.createInputStream();  
                  // is = new FileInputStream(dataPath);
                    if(is != null)
                    data = readBytes(is);
                    param = new Bundle();
                    param.putString("message", dataMsg);
                    param.putString("filename", dataName);
                    param.putByteArray("video", data);
                    mAsyncRunner.request("me/videos", param, "POST", new SampleRequestListener(), null);
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }       
            }
        });
        mUploadButton.setVisibility(mFacebook.isSessionValid() ?
                View.VISIBLE :
                View.INVISIBLE);
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding the mime type

Comment: Please tell me how to do it sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code it used to work
you have to do a little bit of change in fb provided api i hope you would have done that already as you are trying to post vedio(its the async runners converssion of postimage to vedio)-- this is a little old i dont know will it work now

```
   public class SdfgsdActivity extends Activity {
 Facebook facebook = new Facebook("107520172708950");
 byte[] data;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

      /*  facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}


        });*/


        Button facebookButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        facebookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
              //  saveButtonDialog.dismiss();

               // saveImageFunction(); // to save the Image

                //facebook.authorize(SdfgsdActivity.this, new String[]{ "user_photos,publish_checkins,publish_actions,publish_stream"},new DialogListener() {                     
                 facebook.authorize(SdfgsdActivity.this, new String[]{ "offline_access,publish_stream,user_videos"},new DialogListener() {                        
                 public void onComplete(Bundle values) 
                 {  
                            postImageonWall1();
                            Log.e("MWR", "No Way to Share!");

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video on Facebook.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }                      
                    @Override                     
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) 
                    {                     
                    }                      
                    @Override                     
                    public void onError(DialogError e) 
                    {                     
                    }                      
                    @Override                     
                    public void onCancel() 
                    {                     
                    }                 
                }); 
            }
        });





    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    public void postImageonWall() 
    {             
        byte[] data = null;               
        String filename ="image1.jpg";
        String APP_FILE_PATH ="/mnt/sdcard/Recordingimges/";
        Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(APP_FILE_PATH +filename);
        //Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);             
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();              
        bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);              
        data = baos.toByteArray();                
        Bundle params = new Bundle();              
        params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());              
        params.putString("method", "photos.upload");              
        params.putByteArray("picture", data);               
        AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);              
        mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);    
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void postImageonWall1() 
    {    
           Bundle params = new Bundle();



        byte[] data = null;
        String dataName = "tt.3gp";
        String dataPath = "/mnt/sdcard/Video/tt.3gp";
        String dataMsg = "Your video description here.";
        Bundle param;
         Bundle param1 = null;
        //facebook = new Facebook("107520172708950");
         AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
     InputStream is = null;
        try {
        is = new FileInputStream(dataPath);
        data = readBytes(is);
        param = new Bundle();
        params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());              
        param.putString("filename", dataName);
        param.putString("message", dataMsg);
                param.putString("mimeType", "video/3GP");

        param.putByteArray("video", data);
        mAsyncRunner.request("me/videos", param, "POST", new fbRequestListener(), null);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }





    public byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException 
    {
        // This dynamically extends to take the bytes you read.
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // This is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes.
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // We need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer.
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) 
        {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        // And then we can return your byte array.
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }




    public class fbRequestListener implements RequestListener 
    {

        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) 
        {

            Log.d("RESPONSE",""+response);

        }

        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) 
        {

            Log.d("RESPONSE",""+e);

        }

        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) 
        {

            Log.d("RESPONSE",""+e);

        }

        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) 
        {

        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) 
        {


            Log.d("RESPONSE",""+e);

        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your help, but it is not working ,still getting the same error.

Comment: have you editted the facebook api to upload vedio's ? if not try that (to check try uploading image if it works the prob is you have to edit the api to include vedios)

Comment: are you using OAuth to authorize??

Comment: Yes sir ,i have tried 4 other videos which i can run on emulator,but am not able to post them on facebook till now.